# insert data into 2 database using foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

I need to insert 2 data in 2 database. value "company" can be null and can have data."company"is inserted into different table. the problem is, if insert data with "company" is null, the error will be  *ErrorException Undefined array key*. how to insert different data in different table? each table related with each other with foreign key -> id.

```
if (is_countable($data) && count($data) > 0){
      
            foreach ($data['mm_name'] as $item => $value) {
                $data2 = array(
                    'um_id' => $meeting->id,
                    'mm_name' => $data['mm_name'][$item],
                    'mm_email' => $data['mm_email'][$item],
                );
                MeetingMember::create($data2);
            }
        }

        if (is_countable($data) && count($data) > 0){
                foreach ($data['company'] as $company => $value) {
                    $data3 = array(
                        'meeting_id' => $meeting->id,
                        'company' => $data['company'][$company],
                        
                    );
                    AuditMeeting::create($data3);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to check if the content exists before doing this
'company' => $data['company'][$company] 
Company can be null but you can't access a array key that doesn't exist

Comment: Why use `$data['company'][$company]` instead of just `$value` inside your loop?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$data['mm_name'][$item]` must use $value and instead of `$data['company'][$company]` must use $value.

and

change

```
if (is_countable($data) && count($data) > 0){
.
.
.
```

to

```
if (is_countable($data) && count($data) > 0 && isset($data['company'])){
.
.
.
.
```